# How to programatically clean output in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I print output on the console in WPF and ASP.NET-MVC applications by:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("text");
```

how to programatically clear the output window?

Comment: entropic answer works.

Answer (score 5):

```
// Import EnvDTE and EnvDTE80 into your project
using EnvDTE;
using EnvDTE80;

protected void ClearOutput()
{
    DTE2 ide = (DTE2)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.12.0");
    ide.ToolWindows.OutputWindow.OutputWindowPanes.Item("Debug").Clear();
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ide);
}
```

Comment: error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'EnvDTE.OutputWindowPane'. Must remove the "OutputWindowPane pane =" part. It works. This should be the correct answer.

Comment: @Pedro77 Thanks.  In my first attempt I grabbed the pane, then cleared it... realized I can do it in one step and forgot to remove the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use in VS2013, Win10, x64:

```
private static void ClearVS2013DebugWindow()
{
    // add reference to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSEnv\PublicAssemblies\envdte.dll"
    EnvDTE.DTE ide = (EnvDTE.DTE)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.12.0");
    if (ide != null)
    {
        ide.ExecuteCommand("Edit.ClearOutputWindow", "");
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ide);
    }
}
```

Credit to the answers above.

Answer (score 0):

Within the underlying APIs, the debug output is a forward only stream - [you shouldn't assume that it is only viewable within Visual Studio](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx). Debug output can only be written by an application, and if you need more detailed control, it should be shown within the User Interface of your application (whether that is a console window, which can be cleared; or a WinForms application, or WPF, etc.)

Comment: That would only work when the debugger is Visual Studio (and even then, the right version), and not something else like DebugView